# Write image data as a matrix in R

Tags: r

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I have an image data comprised (x,y,z) where x and y are coordinates  and z is say pixel value. I wish to write/ put this as a 2D matrix A, so that A_ij is the z value corresponding to the (i,j)th coordinate.

Here is the snapshot os the data. The Barcodes are not important at the moment.  Any suggestions or help will be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Those aren't integer coordinates though. What is the ith row, if i = 436.64360?

Comment: @Axeman, you are right. The coordinates are of double  type and that's part of the dilemma. If it is of any help, here is  a little  background; the data is from a tissue sample,  these are spatial coordinates of regions within the sample where some gene is expressed  ("seen").  I hope my matrix will have the property that neighboring values in the matrix will correspond to neighboring spots within the tissue

Comment: So, the immediate challenge is to get the data out of an image in usable form, say perhaps using the png above?

Comment: Double type of coordinates is the main problem. You need to limit them to a set of values that will become your rows and columns. Then you only initiate and fill your matrix. Depending on the required precision (number of decimal points, interval between 2 values) you may have very large and very spare matrix, which is hard to manage. I guess you wish to use some image processing method afterward. Isn't there other option to answer your question? Clustering?